# Is there a user access analytics middleware or module for django?

Tags: django, analytics

I have found other solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609924/django-saving-the-whole-request-for-statistics-whats-available) but this example collects raw data, I need something a little bit more processed, I need an user-centric analytics. Those statistics  are for advertising purposes. I want to recollect as much information as possible.

Comment: Did you consider using google analytics? With template inheritance, including the Analytics snippet is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method might add a lot of overhead to each page load especially if you have a busy site / database server. I would recommend using google analytics on the template of each page instead. At least the analytics data is handled after the users page load.

I believe google has an api if you need to take the information from analytics and display it on your site.