# Django log request for analytics

Tags: django, statistics, analytics

I want to store information for every `request` made to my site. For example `USER_AGENT` etc. Like `google analytics` do. And then I want to expose that information using `rest-API`. Is their any APP for this.???

Comment: I don't know if there are apps, but this shouldn't be that hard to do. If you want to track every request, just add a middleware that captures it and use django-rest to expose it.

Comment: Found middleware solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609924/django-saving-the-whole-request-for-statistics-whats-available